# Add first two elements together, remove them, and push into a new array until there is nothing left in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, sum

> //Write a method `adjacent_sum` that takes in an array of numbers and returns a new array containing the sums of adjacent numbers in the original array.

This is my problem.

```js
function adjacent_sum(arr) {
    let newArr = []

    while (arr.length > 0) {
      let sum = arr[0] + arr[1]
      newArr.push(sum)
      arr.splice(0,2)
    }
  return newArr;
  console.log(newArr)


adjacent_sum([3, 7, 2, 11]); // [10, 9, 13], because [ 3+7, 7+2, 2+11 ]

adjacent_sum([2, 5, 1, 9, 2, 4]); // [7, 6, 10, 11, 6], because [2+5, 5+1, 1+9, 9+2, 2+4]
```

Basically I am trying to add the first two elements of the array, push the sum into a new array, then remove those elements until there is nothing left in the array.

Comment: What is the issue you're facing with this code? I.e. what is your question?

Comment: Start by fixing any errors what pop up in your console like the missing closing bracket of the function.

Comment: You shouldn't remove 2 elements each time, just 1. And stop when the array has only 1 element.

Comment: You're missing the `}` at the end of the function.

Comment: @Barmar I am only looking to add the sum of the adjacent elements.

Comment: @Teemu My code does not seem to be working. I believe the syntax might be wrong somewhere?

Comment: I know that. But when you remove both 3 and 7, you can't do `7+2`. You should only remove 3.

Comment: I told you the syntax error: You're missing a `}`.

Comment: @Barmar I fixed the syntax error. And I only am now taking 1 element away at a time. I am getting NaN at the end of my newArr now. Coming out to this [10, 9, 13, NAN]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your missing the `}` from the `adjacent_sum` function
2. Since you want to group by 2, you should just remove (`splice()`) 1 item from the array, since you'll still need the other one on the next iteration
3. Due to #2, we'll need to change the `while` to stop if there's only 1 element left: `(arr.length > 1)`
4. The `console.log()` was never executed since it was after the `return`. I've placed the function call inside a `console.log()` to show the `return` value of the function

```js
function adjacent_sum(arr) {
    let newArr = []

    while (arr.length > 1) {
      let sum = arr[0] + arr[1]
      newArr.push(sum)
      arr.splice(0,1)
    }
    return newArr;
}
  
console.log(adjacent_sum([3, 7, 2, 11]));
// [10, 9, 13], because [ 3+7, 7+2, 2+11 ]

console.log(adjacent_sum([2, 5, 1, 9, 2, 4])); 
// [7, 6, 10, 11, 6], because [2+5, 5+1, 1+9, 9+2, 2+4]
```